# Group column name in database which has same value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making a program to add number of stores which has their own opening and closing hours( Which may be different for different days)

My database structure for storing opening and closing hours is as

[image]

so while fetching my data from this table I want to group column name having same value..

like for first store output should be

```
monday, tuesday, wednesday, thrusday, friday, saturday, sunday => 10:00-am to 8:00-pm
```

And for last store output should be

```
monday, tuesday, wednesday, friday, saturday => 10:00-am to 8:00-pm

thrusday => 9:30-am to 5:00-pm

sunday => 10:00-am to 4:30-pm
```

So how I can write query to fetch records like this..

Thank you,

Comment: make array of column value and value of the array will be the column name if value is same otherwise make new array

Comment: you want output in array ? like ----> $result = ['monday, tuesday, wednesday, friday, saturday' => '10:00-am to 8:00-pm', 'thrusday' => '9:30-am to 5:00-pm', 'sunday' => '10:00-am to 4:30-pm']

Comment: @Monty, yes It will also work...

Answer (score 0):

Might this will help you.

`$array` = which is coming from the database and treating its input as of now.

`$standardTime` = the array which holds the default opening and closing time for stores.

I am not sure how this will possible with the SQL or direct by the query but, here I have tried to do with the PHP script. Hope this will help you.

```
    $array =  array(
      'monday' => "10:30-am to 08:00-pm",
      'tuesday' => "10:30-am to 08:00-pm",
      'wedensday' => "10:30-am to 08:00-pm",
      'thursday' => "09:30-am to 05:00-pm",
      'friday' => "10:30-am to 08:00-pm",
      'saturday' => "10:30-am to 08:00-pm",
      'sunday' => "10:00-am to 04:30-pm",
    );

    $standardTime = array("10:30-am to 08:00-pm","10:30-am to 08:00-pm","10:30-am to 08:00-pm","10:30-am to 08:00-pm","10:30-am to 08:00-pm","10:30-am to 08:00-pm","10:30-am to 08:00-pm");
    $diff = array_diff($array,$standardTime);
    $daysWithDiffTimmings = '';
    if(is_array($diff) && count($diff) > 0) {
        $daysThatHaveDiffTime = array_keys($diff);
        foreach($daysThatHaveDiffTime as $day) {
            $daysWithDiffTimmings.= $day.' = '.$diff[$day]."<br/>";
            unset($array[$day]);
       }
     }

    $remainingDaysWithSameTime = array_keys($array);
    $daysWithSameTime =  implode(",", $remainingDaysWithSameTime);
    $daysWithSameTime .= ' = 10:30-am to 08:00-pm<br/>';

    echo $daysWithSameTime;
    echo $daysWithDiffTimmings;
```

This will give you output as:

```
monday,tuesday,wedensday,friday,saturday = 10:30-am to 08:00-pm
thursday = 09:30-am to 05:00-pm
sunday = 10:00-am to 04:30-pm
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
$question = array(
        'monday' => '10:00-am to 8:00-pm',
        'tuesday' => '10:00-am to 8:00-pm',
        'wednesday' => '10:00-am to 8:00-pm',
        'thrusday' => '9:30-am to 5:00-pm',
        'friday' => '10:00-am to 8:00-pm',
        'saturday' => '10:00-am to 8:00-pm',
        'sunday' => '10:00-am to 4:30-pm',
    );
$result = array();
foreach ($question as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($result[$value]))
        $result[$value] .= ', '.$key;
    else
        $result[$value] = $key;
}
echo "<pre>".print_r(array_flip($result),1)."</pre>";
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [monday, tuesday, wednesday, friday, saturday] => 10:00-am to 8:00-pm
    [thrusday] => 9:30-am to 5:00-pm
    [sunday] => 10:00-am to 4:30-pm
)
```